# importing foreign key columns into model from visual studio 2008

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I got a question about foreign key when "importing" the db into visual studio.

my development environment:

SQL 2005/2008/2008R2

Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET MVC 2 with .Net framework 3.5 SP1

was following the MVC music store V1.0

in the tutorial pdf, page 50, it says when we creating the "Entity Data Model" at the last stage, we should select "Include foreign key columns in the model.

however, i am using VS2008 and when at this stage there is no such foreign key option to choose.

[image]

plz notice that inside the red circle, it should contain (AlbumId, GenreId, ArtistId, Title, Price, AlbumArtURL) as shown in tutotial

[image]

but my model is missing GenreId and ArtistId.

how to deal with it?

I encountered a problem later when the i creating edit form and need to use something like [[[[<%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenreId) %>]]]]] it is not working.

so i need the GenreId and ArtistId to appear in the Album. i guess it is about the foreign key problem...

do you know how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Importing foreign key columns is feature of EFv4 so you need .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 to use it.

In your case you must access FK value through `EntityObject` based API. Your entity should have property like `GenreReference` so you can use something like:

```
int genreId = (int)entity.GenreReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0];
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, i can get the fk value but actually i got stuck at Edit postback mtd where html code for dropdown is as <%= Html.DropDownList("ArtistId", new SelectList(ViewData["Artists"] as IEnumerable, "ArtistId", "Name", Model.ArtistId))%> in controller i have used the updatemodel() mtd, it updates the properties of Album table, but fail to update the FK reference values i.e. artistid and genereid in Album table this might be because in our .edmx model there are no such properties as generId and artistId ...